# How can I fetch all items from a DynamoDB table without specifying the primary key?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table called products with primary key `Id`. I want to select all items in the table. This is the code is I'm using:

```
$batch_get_response = $dynamodb->batch_get_item(array(
    'RequestItems' => array(

        'products' => array(
            'Keys' => array(
                array( // Key #1
                    'HashKeyElement'  => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER => '1'),
                    'RangeKeyElement' => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER => $current_time),
                ),
                array( // Key #2
                    'HashKeyElement'  => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER => '2'),
                    'RangeKeyElement' => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER => $current_time),
                ),
            )
        )
    )   
));
```

Is it possible to select all items without specifying the primary key? I'm using the AWS SDK for PHP.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) provides the [Scan](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Scan.html) operation for this purpose, which *returns one or more items and its attributes by performing a full scan of a table*. Please be aware of the following two constraints:

- Depending on your table size, you may need to use pagination to retrieve the entire result set:

  > **Note**
  >   If the total number of scanned items exceeds the 1MB limit, the
  >   scan stops and results are returned to the user with a
  >   LastEvaluatedKey to continue the scan in a subsequent operation. The
  >   results also include the number of items exceeding the limit. A scan
  >   can result in no table data meeting the filter criteria.
  >
  > The result set is eventually consistent.
- The Scan operation is potentially costly regarding both performance and consumed capacity units (i.e. price), see section *Scan and Query Performance* in [Query and Scan in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html):

  > [...] Also, as a table grows, the scan operation slows. The scan
  >   operation examines every item for the requested values, and **can use up
  >   the provisioned throughput for a large table in a single operation**.
  >   For quicker response times, design your tables in a way that can use
  >   the Query, Get, or BatchGetItem APIs, instead. Or, design your
  >   application to use scan operations in a way that minimizes the impact
  >   on your table's request rate. For more information, see [Provisioned
  >   Throughput Guidelines in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html). *[emphasis mine]*

You can find more details about this operation and some example snippets in [Scanning Tables Using the AWS SDK for PHP Low-Level API for Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPScanning.html), with the most simple example illustrating the operation being:

```
$dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();

$scan_response = $dynamodb->scan(array(
    'TableName' => 'ProductCatalog' 
));

foreach ($scan_response->body->Items as $item)
{
    echo "<p><strong>Item Number:</strong>"
         . (string) $item->Id->{AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER};
    echo "<br><strong>Item Name: </strong>"
         . (string) $item->Title->{AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING} ."</p>";
}
```

Comment: is it possible to add condition in the query?

Comment: Yes, check the _Request_ section for [Scan](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Scan.html), `ScanFilter:ComparisonOperator` provides a summary of what you can do. Depending on your scenario, you may want to look into [Query](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query.html) as well, which is usually preferable both for performance and cost reasons (but requires a primary key), as addressed in [Query and Scan in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html).

Comment: can u look on to my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477996/writing-complex-queries-in-amazone-dynamo-dbmathematical-expressions

Comment: Is it possible to get the last inserted id (MAX of primay Id)?

Comment: @THOmas: No, the [Primary Key](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModelPrimaryKey) is either a _Hash Type Primary Key_ or a _Hash and Range Type Primary Key_; the latter allows relative order of items (see the `RangeKeyCondition` of [Query](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query.html), but that's about it. Accordingly (as usual for NoSQL solutions), if you really need this, you would need to model it yourself (after all, you inserted the key) - you seem to still think too much in SQL terms here ;)

Comment: So when i am inserting new product what should i assign to the id field ?

Comment: @THOmas: That's entirely up to you, i.e. it depends on how you model your problem domain, thus it is actually unrelated to DynamoDB.

Comment: @THOmas: Regarding DynamoDB, I suggest you read through [Getting Started with Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStartedDynamoDB.html), there are PHP samples for all steps as well. [Creating a Table](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPCreateUpdateDeleteTable.html#sect-create-tables) shows how the usual integer based id is modeled and [Putting an Item](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPItemCRUD.html#PutLowLevelAPIPHP) how it is used in turn.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11015/discussion-between-thomas-and-steffen-opel)

Answer (score 24):

Hi you can download using boto3. In python

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Table')
response = table.scan()
items = response['Items']
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    print(response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    items.extend(response['Items'])
```

Comment: A link to the lib/ documentation would be great.

Comment: Isn't scan a costly operation?! @Steffen Opel explained that quite well.

Comment: @Ronnie Yes, is it. However, OP wants to pull all rows from the table. Query is going to be just as costly.

Answer (score 10):

I figured you are using PHP but not mentioned (edited). I found this question by searching internet and since I got solution working , **for those who use nodejs** here is a simple solution using scan :

```
  var dynamoClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  var params = {
    TableName: config.dynamoClient.tableName, // give it your table name 
    Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES"
  };

  dynamoClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
       console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
       console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
  });
```

I assume **same code can be translated to PHP** too **using different AWS SDK**

Answer (score 2):

I fetch all items from dynamodb with the following query. It works fine. i create these function generic in zend framework and access these functions over the project.

```
        public function getQuerydata($tablename, $filterKey, $filterValue){
            return $this->getQuerydataWithOp($tablename, $filterKey, $filterValue, 'EQ');
        }

        public function getQuerydataWithOp($tablename, $filterKey, $filterValue, $compOperator){
        $result = $this->getClientdb()->query(array(
                'TableName'     => $tablename,
                'IndexName'     => $filterKey,
                'Select'        => 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
                'KeyConditions' => array(
                    $filterKey => array(
                        'AttributeValueList' => array(
                            array('S' => $filterValue)
                        ),
                'ComparisonOperator' => $compOperator
            )
            )
        ));
            return $result['Items'];
        }

       //Below i Access these functions and get data.
       $accountsimg = $this->getQuerydataWithPrimary('accounts', 'accountID',$msgdata[0]['accountID']['S']);
```

Comment: How many records are in your database? There's a limit of 1MB, it seems like this would work great for smaller databases, but wouldn't get everything if you had some substantial data in there.

Comment: you can use limit parameters that amazon db provide when if you get records greater than 1 MB.

Comment: From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#FilteringResults : "A single Query or Scan operation can retrieve a maximum of 1 MB of data. This limit applies before any filter expression is applied to the results.
"

Comment: does not get ALL items as OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

A simple code to list all the Items from DynamoDB Table by specifying the region of AWS Service.

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-south-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('puppy_store')
response = table.scan()
items = response['Items']

# Prints All the Items at once
print(items)

# Prints Items line by line
for i, j in enumerate(items):
    print(f"Num: {i} --> {j}")
```

Comment: I was missing the extra 's' from item.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for Java. In withAttributesToGet you specify what exactly you want to read. Before run you have to place credential file to your .aws folder.

```
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";

    public static final AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.CA_CENTRAL_1)
            .build();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        downloadAllRecords();
    }

    public static void downloadAllRecords() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        final Object[] FILE_HEADER = {"key", "some_param"};
        CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator("\n");
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(new FileWriter(TABLE_NAME + ".csv"), csvFormat);
        csvPrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

        ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
                .withTableName(TABLE_NAME)
                .withConsistentRead(false)
                .withLimit(100)
                .withAttributesToGet("key", "some_param");
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
            Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = result.getLastEvaluatedKey();
            for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()) {
                AttributeValue keyIdAttribute = item.getOrDefault("key", new AttributeValue());
                AttributeValue createdDateAttribute = item.getOrDefault("some_param", new AttributeValue());

                    counter++;
                    List record = new ArrayList();
                    record.add(keyIdAttribute.getS());
                    record.add(createdDateAttribute.getS());
                    csvPrinter.printRecord(record);
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);

            }
            scanRequest.setExclusiveStartKey(lastEvaluatedKey);
        } while (scanRequest.getExclusiveStartKey() != null);
        csvPrinter.flush();
        csvPrinter.close();
        System.out.println("CSV file generated successfully.");
    }
```

Also specify necessary dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.4</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sparkjava/spark-template-velocity -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-template-velocity</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-logs -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-logs</artifactId>
       <version>1.12.132</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.9</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
       <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
       <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
       <version>4.4</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
       <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
       <version>5.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
       <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
       <version>1.12.161</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
   </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Example of credential file

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AAAAAAA
aws_secret_access_key = AAAAAAAA
aws_session_token = AAAAAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not specifying a pk on following code:

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
table = 'table_name'
response = client.scan(
    TableName=table,
    AttributesToGet=['second_field_in_order', 'first_field_in_order']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A method to fetch all rows without using the primary key, and without running a Scan, is to define/add a GSI (global secondary index) on the table, with an additional attribute that you can specify as the GSI key. Set this value to the same value in each row (unless you want to use it for multiple purposes)

You then do a Query on the GSI specifying the value of the added attribute.

You might have to paginate the returned values.

Using a GSI will increase the size of the table, and may increase costs.

Answer (score -3):

This C# code is to fetch all items from a dynamodb table using BatchGet or CreateBatchGet

```
        string tablename = "AnyTableName"; //table whose data you want to fetch

        var BatchRead = ABCContext.Context.CreateBatchGet<ABCTable>(  

            new DynamoDBOperationConfig
            {
                OverrideTableName = tablename; 
            });

        foreach(string Id in IdList) // in case you are taking string from input
        {
            Guid objGuid = Guid.Parse(Id); //parsing string to guid
            BatchRead.AddKey(objGuid);
        }

        await BatchRead.ExecuteAsync();
        var result = BatchRead.Results;
```

// ABCTable is the table modal which is used to create in dynamodb & data you want to fetch