# Writing Complex queries in Amazon Dynamo DB(Mathematical expressions)

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I have switched from mysql to Dynamo DB .In mysql i have used a query for fetching all the users nearer to a particular latitude and longitude.The query is

```
SELECT *,SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( latitude - $latitude) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( $longitude - longitude ) * COS( latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) AS distance FROM coupon WHERE is_active='Y' HAVING distance<=$radius
```

is it possible to create a query like in Dynamo DB.I am using PHP as my Backend

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) does not offer complex SQL queries like this one out of the box, after all, something has to go when you want to use a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database ;)

However, given that DynamoDB has been developed specifically for use cases requiring *fast and predictable performance with seamless scalability*, which usually implies respectively large datasets, it provides integration with [Amazon Elastic MapReduce (Amazon EMR)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) for use cases like yours:

> Amazon DynamoDB also integrates with Amazon Elastic MapReduce (Amazon
>   EMR). Amazon EMR allows businesses to perform complex analytics of
>   their large datasets using a hosted pay-as-you-go Hadoop framework on
>   AWS. [...] Businesses can also use
>   Amazon EMR to access data in multiple stores (i.e. Amazon DynamoDB,
>   Amazon RDS, and Amazon S3), do complex analysis over this combined
>   dataset, and store the results of this work in Amazon S3.

You may want to read into [Exporting, Importing, Querying, and Joining Tables in Amazon DynamoDB Using Amazon EMR for details](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.html), which summarizes *Querying live Amazon DynamoDB data using SQL-like statements (HiveQL)*, amongst other things. While [HiveQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveQL) provides a bit more than DynamoDB itself, it is still a *simple SQL-like query language*, and mathematical expressions like yours are not covered.

For these you'd need to dive into [Hadoop and MapReduce](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/elasticmapreduceandHadoop.html) (as provided by the DynamoDB EMR integration), as it allows you to do pretty much anything what you want with your data (see e.g. [How to Create a Job Flow Using a Custom JAR](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/CLI_JobFlowUsingCustomJAR.html)).