# How to get item from table by attirbute using dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to retrieve items from the table where an attribute is equal to a value I specify using dynomodb.

The SQL equivalent is.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tokens where type='app_access_token`
```

**Code:**

```js
    copnst db = new Dynamodb.DocumentClient(credentials);

    const params = {
      TableName: 'TOKEN',
      Key: {
        type: 'app_access_token'
      }
    };

    const response = db.get(params).promise();
```

But I believe this will only let me get via primary key, is that right?

**No SQL WorkBench Structure**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplication, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10451629/409315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB's equivalent of `SELECT *` is the `scan` method. They are both scanning all of the table records (and hence, slow and expensive).

You can learn more about the `scan` method in [Amazon Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html) or in this [useful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450962/how-can-i-fetch-all-items-from-a-dynamodb-table-without-specifying-the-primary-k/10451629#10451629).

If you can, I would use a GSI with the attribute `type` as key, but if you still want to do it with `scan` method, here's how you do it:

```
const params = {
  TableName : 'TOKEN',
  FilterExpression : 'type = :type',
  ExpressionAttributeValues : {':type' : 'app_access_token'}
};

const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const response = documentClient.scan(params).promise();
```

[AWS JavaScript SDK - DocumentClient Scan()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property)